# weak convergence of independent sequence

Tags: measure-theory

I want to show that if $X_n\to^w X$ and $Y_n\to^w Y$ which is 'weak convergence'

and the $X_n,Y_n$ are independent RV's on the same probability space,

Then we also have weak convergence of the random vector $(X_n,Y_n)\to^w (X,Y)$
Apparantly he independence condition is crucial here ..

I only know that the joint probability distribution is the product of both
distributions. I'm not sure how this implies weak convergence of the random vector..

Comment: Are the random variables real valued?

Comment: yes sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Use the Cramer Wold then compute the characteristic function using independence.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be independent?

Comment: No, so aparantly this follows...isn't it true that $X_n,Y_n$ independant implies $X,Y$ independant.?

Comment: What is $(X_n, Y_n) \xrightarrow{w} (X, Y)$ to you?

Comment: To me this means that for every continuous $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ we have $\mathbb{E}f(X_n,Y_n)\to \mathbb{E}f(X,Y)$

Comment: @DinkyDoe: not every continuous...

Comment: That is the definition I'm used to work with ..I remember this could be taken as an alternative definition of weak convergence.

Comment: Convergence in distribution has nothing to do with the domain, while independence does.
Consider the probability space $[0,1]^2$ with uniform distirbution and let $X_n(x,y) = x$ and $Y_n(x,y) = y$.
Then, $X_n \xrightarrow{w} X_1$ and $Y_n \xrightarrow{w} X_1$.
So, the limit might not be independent.

Comment: oh, i meant continuous and bounded functions f :PP

Comment: @DinkyDoe: You are welcome! PS: If you use an "@" before my name, I am warned by the system about the message and then I can reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, this is false.

Take $\Omega = [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}} \times [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$.
And let
$$
  X_n(x,y) = x_n
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  Y_n(x,y) = y_n.
$$
Then, $X_n \xrightarrow{w} X_1$ and $Y_n \xrightarrow{w} X_1$ (not a typo!).

But $(X_n, Y_n)$ is identically distributed, so
$(X_n, Y_n) \xrightarrow{w} (X_1, Y_1)$
which has a different distribution from $(X_1, X_1)$.

For the result to be true, you will have to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
That is, $(X_n, Y_n) \not \xrightarrow{w} (X_1, X_1)$.

Comment: Can you explain why $X_n \xrightarrow{w} X_1$ and $Y_n \xrightarrow{w} X_1$?