# If independent sequences weakly converge, their product weakly converges.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

This is a duplicate of [weak convergence of independent sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234398/weak-convergence-of-independent-sequence) , but I don't think that answer actually answers the question.

Let $(X_n), (Y_n)$ be independent sequences, weakly converging to $X$ and $Y$ respectively, who are also independent. I want to show that $\langle X_n, Y_n \rangle \xrightarrow{w} \langle X, Y \rangle$.

For $(X_n)$ to weakly converge to $X$, means by definition that $\int f d \mathbb{P}^{X_n}$ converges to $\int f d \mathbb{P}^X$ for any continuous bounded $f$, or equivalently that $\int f \circ X_n d \mathbb{P}$ converges to $\int f \circ X d \mathbb{P}$.

For showing that $\int h \circ \langle X_n, Y_n \rangle d \mathbb{P}$ converges to $\int h \circ \langle X, Y \rangle d \mathbb{P}$, I think the idea is to look at $"h \circ X"$ and $"h \circ Y"$, where the "" are because $h$ takes its arguments in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and there is no canonical injection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

To get an idea on how to solve this, I thought we could first have a look at $h$ an indicator function $1_{A \times B}$. Then we get that

$\int 1_{A \times B} \circ \langle X_n, Y_n \rangle d \mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}(X_n^{-1}(A) \cap Y_n^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb{P}(X_n^{-1}(A)) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y_n^{-1}(B)) =$

$\int 1_{A} \circ X d \mathbb{P} \cdot \int 1_{B} \cdot Y d \mathbb{P}$ by independence, which looks promising as it at least uses the independence and splits up the integral, but I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: The easiest way to prove this is to use characteristic functions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy We haven't covered characteristic functions (at least not measure-theoretically). Can't this approach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is on the right track.  What you're getting at is the fact that any function of the form $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$ satisfies
$$
\int f \circ (X_n,Y_n) \,d\mathbb{P} = \int (g\circ X_n) (h \circ Y_n) \,d\mathbb{P} = \int g \circ X_n \,d\mathbb{P} \cdot \int h \circ Y_n \,d\mathbb{P} \to \int g \circ X \,d\mathbb{P} \cdot \int h \circ Y \,d\mathbb{P}  
$$
as $n \to \infty$.  Then you can use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to prove that the set of functions of the form $(x,y) \mapsto g(x)h(y)$ is dense in the set of all continuous functions.