# Multidimensional distribution weak convergence for vectors with independent entries

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, independence, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_n \overset d \to X, Y_n \overset d \to Y$ where $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent, as well as $X$ and $Y$. Then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
X_n \\
Y_n
\end{bmatrix} \overset d \to
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\
Y
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
How do you prove that?

---

I am aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924816/if-independent-sequences-weakly-converge-their-product-weakly-converges) previously asked question, but the answer uses Stone-Weierstrass theorem which I don't get. I think author meant to approximate given bounded continuous function by linear combination of 2-variable polynomials of the form $P(x)Q(y)$, but I never used this theorem before, so I'm not sure. And besides, approximating with polynomials which are not bounded (that is most of them) may not satisfy $\int Q \operatorname d \! \mu_n \to \int Q \operatorname d \! \mu $ where $\mu$ and $\mu_n$ are appropriate distributions.

---

I tired to do this in a different way, but couldn't finish if off:

We want to show, that for any conitnous and bounded function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ we have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left|\int_{\mathbb R^2} f \operatorname d \! \mu_n \times \nu_n
- \int_{\mathbb R^2} f \operatorname d \! \mu \times \nu\right| = 0.
$$
Using triangle inequality as well as Fubini's theorem
$$\begin{align}
&\left|\int_{\mathbb R^2} f \operatorname d \! \mu_n \times \nu_n
- \int_{\mathbb R^2} f \operatorname d \! \mu \times \nu\right| \\  &\leq
\left|\int_{\mathbb R^2} f \operatorname d \! \mu_n \times \nu_n
- \int_{\mathbb R^2} f \operatorname d \! \mu \times \nu_n\right| +
\left|\int_{\mathbb R^2} f \operatorname d \! \mu \times \nu_n
- \int_{\mathbb R^2} f \operatorname d \! \mu \times \nu\right| \\ & =
\left|\int_{\mathbb R}\left(\int_{\mathbb R} f(x, y) \operatorname d \! \mu_n(x) 
-\int_{\mathbb R} f(x, y) \operatorname d \! \mu(x) \right)\operatorname d \! \nu_n(y)\right| +
\left|\int_{\mathbb R} g \operatorname d \! \nu_n
- \int_{\mathbb R} g \operatorname d \! \nu\right|,
\end{align}$$
where $g(y) = \int_\mathbb{R}f(x, y) \operatorname d \! \mu(x)$. We can easly see that $g$ is bounded, and using dominated convergence theorem show it is continuous, so the last term will approach $0$.

However first term is quite problematic. Inside function will approach $0$ everywhere, but as the function changes so does the measure with respect to which we are integrating. In general it is easy to find sequence of continuous bounded functions $h_n$ which approach $0$, and sequence of probability measures $\xi_n$ such that $\int h_n \operatorname d\! \xi_n = 1$, for example $h_n(t) = (1 - |t - n|)^+$ and $\xi_n = \delta_{\{n\}}$. But in our problem we assume that the measure converges weakly, which my example does not satisfy.

---

Can anyone complete my proof or maybe explain solution of the previous question?

Comment: There is a one line proof using characterstic functions.

Comment: Well, I don't know about characteristic functions of random vectors yet. Perhaps its good time to learn them ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a proof of the weak convergence of multidimensional distribution for vectors
with independent (weak convergent) components.

Let $\mathscr{D}=\{f_u,u\in U\} $ be a collection of  functions in $C(\mathbb{R})$, which separates
points in $\mathbb{R}$. It is easy to verify that
\begin{equation*}
  \mathscr{D}_2=\{h_w=h_w(x,y)=(f_u(x),g_v(y)),\, w=(u,v)\in U\times U\}   \tag{1} 
\end{equation*}
is also a collection of functions in $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$, which separates points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hence for each finite interval $I_M=[-M,M]$ and $ I_M^2=[-M,M]\times[-M,M]$, except at most a countable $M$,
\begin{gather*}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{I_M} f_u(x)\,\mu_n(\mathrm{d}x)=\int_{I_M} f_u(x)\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x), \quad \forall f_u\in\mathscr{D}, \\ 
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{I_M} g_v(y)\,\nu_n(\mathrm{d}y)=\int_{I_M} g_v(y)\,\nu(\mathrm{d}y),\quad \forall g_u\in\mathscr{D},\\
\begin{aligned}
 \lim_{n\to\infty} &\int_{I_M^2} f_u(x)g_v(y)\,(\mu_n\times\nu_n)(\mathrm{d}x\times\mathrm{d}y)\\
 &=\int_{I_M^2} f_u(x)g_v(y)\,(\mu\times\nu)(\mathrm{d}x\times\mathrm{d}y), 
 \qquad \forall f_ug_v\in\mathscr{D}_2.
\end{aligned}\tag{2}
\end{gather*}
Furthermore, using Stone-Weierstrass Theorem and from (2),
\begin{align*}
 &\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{I_M^2} f(x,y)\,(\mu_n\times\nu_n)(\mathrm{d}x\times\mathrm{d}y)\\
 &\quad=\int_{I_M^2} f(x,y)\,(\mu\times\nu)(\mathrm{d}x\times\mathrm{d}y), 
 \quad \forall f\in C(\mathbb{R}^2). \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Meanwhile, the $ \{\mu_n,\,n\ge 1\}, \{\nu_n,\,n\ge 1\} $ are tight, since they are weakly convergent, i.e.
\begin{gather*}
 \lim_{M\to\infty}\sup_{n\ge 1}\mu_n(\mathbb{R}\setminus I_M)=0,\\
 \lim_{M\to\infty}\sup_{n\ge 1}\nu_n(\mathbb{R}\setminus I_M)=0,
\end{gather*}
Hence,
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{M\to\infty}\sup_{n\ge 1}[(\mu_n\times\nu_n)(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus I_M^2)]=0. \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
Now for a bounded function $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^2)$,
\begin{align*}
 \Big|\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f\,\mathrm{d}&(\mu_n\times\nu_n)
  -\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f\,\mathrm{d}(\mu\times\nu)\Big|\\ 
  & \le \Big|\int_{I_M^2}f\,\mathrm{d}(\mu_n\times\nu_n)
  -\int_{I_M^2}f\,\mathrm{d}(\mu\times\nu)\Big|\\
  &\quad +\|f\|[(\mu_n\times\nu_n)(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus I_M^2)]
  + \|f\|[(\mu\times\nu)(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus I_M^2)].
\end{align*}
Using above inequality and (3),
\begin{align*}
 &\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}\Big|\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f\,\mathrm{d}(\mu_n\times\nu_n)
 -\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f\,\mathrm{d}(\mu\times\nu)\Big|\\
 &\qquad \le \|f\| \{\sup_{n\ge 1}[(\mu_n\times\nu_n)(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus I_M^2)]
 +(\mu\times\nu)(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus I_M^2)\}
\end{align*}
Now letting $M\to\infty$ and from (4)  get
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f\,\mathrm{d}(\mu_n\times\nu_n)
 =\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f\,\mathrm{d}(\mu\times\nu),\quad \forall f\in C_b(\mathbb{R}^2).
\end{equation*}